# setContentView(view) vs setContentView(R.layout..)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Hello I want to make an application which uses Multi-touch support.

for multitouch i am using [this code](https://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/)

Now in that you can see that there is **org.metalev.multitouch.photosortr.PhotoSortrActivity** Activity
in that the code is like below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle(R.string.instructions);
    photoSorter = new PhotoSortrView(this);
    setContentView(photoSorter);
}
```

it will work fine

but instead of this if i want to add this view in my view i write above code like below...

i have make one XML file named activity_main.xml

```
<org.metalev.multitouch.photosortr.PhotoSortrView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</org.metalev.multitouch.photosortr.PhotoSortrView>
```

and in onCreate method i have change like below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle(R.string.instructions);
    photoSorter = new PhotoSortrView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

if i do like this way i will get an error below is logcat

```
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at org.metalev.multitouch.photosortr.PhotoSortrView$Img.draw(PhotoSortrView.java:274)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at org.metalev.multitouch.photosortr.PhotoSortrView.onDraw(PhotoSortrView.java:86)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6914)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6917)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
10-30 12:15:29.319: E/AndroidRuntime(6652):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
```

in PhotoSortrView.java file the code is like below where i m getting this error

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    float dx = (maxX + minX) / 2;
    float dy = (maxY + minY) / 2;
    ---->drawable.setBounds((int) minX, (int) minY, (int) maxX, (int) maxY); // HERE getting drawable == NULL
    canvas.translate(dx, dy);
    canvas.rotate(angle * 180.0f / (float) Math.PI);
    canvas.translate(-dx, -dy);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only cause might be that `drawable` used in `draw()` of `Img` class is null, since `canvas` is passed by system, and rest variables in method are primitives. This variable is initialized in `load()` of `Img` class , which in turn is called from `loadImages()` of `PhotoSortrView` class.

Now, I guess you are calling `loadImages()` of `photoSorter` variable from Activity's `onResume()` . But there is another `PhotoSortrView` instance created from inflating the layout. Make sure you call `loadImages()` of that instance also.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion to wingman i have solved like below way :

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle(R.string.instructions);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    photoSorter = (PhotoSortrView)findViewById(R.id.photoSortView);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    photoSorter.loadImages(this);
}
```

And in PhotosorterView.java file code is below .

```
    public PhotoSortrView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public PhotoSortrView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public PhotoSortrView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}
```